# Does MSBuild have an equivalent to the NAnt filterchain functionality for replacing tokens in files?

Tags: msbuild, nant

The NAnt task for copying files allows you to specify a filterchain that modifies the files as they are copied, and this is usually used for replacing tokens in a template file with specific values (e.g. substituting in a build number).

Does MSBuild have equivalent functionality in one of its built-in tasks, or one of the freely available community tasks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [standard msbuild tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7z253716.aspx) doesn't mention anything like that, but there's the FileUpdate task in the extensions at http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/ that lets you easily do replacements in files based on regular expressions.